# Issue wile running Bonnet: Crop weed segmentation

Tags: windows, tensorflow, deep-learning, anaconda, image-segmentation

I am trying to run the [Bonnet](https://github.com/PRBonn/bonnet/tree/master/train_py) on an Anaconda platform from the terminal and it runs good for a single image but cannot run for multiple images on my system as specified in the link.

I have a Windows 10 Pro system.

> Error : No image to open for C:/Users/agritech_admin/Anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/bonnet-master/train_py/data/26Jul19/*

I also tried *.jpg but it also doesn't work.

Any idea why I am seeing this error?